# Angular2 parse string to html

Tags: html, parsing, angular

I'm importing rss items where in description there is a lot of html code (links, paragraphs, etc...). When I'm viewing it in component's view like:

```
{{rss.description}}
```

the output in site is like:

```
<a href="http://link.com">Something</a> <p>Long text</p>
```

How can I quickly and easy parse it to html? I don't want to cross it with jQuery. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to add HTML that is interpreted by the browser as markup?

Comment: If your data from Angular can be different types like you state: links, paragraphs, ect. You would have to check them dynamically in javascript and then build the elements that way. There is no standard functionality in angular to take: `google.com` and create `<a href="http://google.com">blah</a>` I hope I understood your question correctly

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but this might be what you want

```
<div [innerHTML]="rss.description"></div>
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax) for how to allow "unsafe" HTML.

Comment: I was using tinymce and when I retrieved from the DB the posted content of the editor I wanted to display it as html and this did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="innerhtml-class" [innerHTML]="variable.innerHtml"></div>
```

To add styles:

Component selector is: app-my-component

Add a class to the element hosting the innerHtml content in app-my-component template:

Add to the global styles file located in angular project src folder:

```
app-my-component { 
 .innerhtml-class { 
   declaration goes here 
 } 
}
```