# Value not set with Angular2 and IE 11 (shims added)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

First, let me say, yes I have included the shims in my index.html.

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js">
</script>
```

I'm using Angular2 beta-17.

The string properties below are all resolved fine except for the image style in IE.

In IE, the name and address properties show fine, but the style is
completely removed from the img tag.  This works fine in all other browsers

```
Name: {{recipient.name}} <br/>
Address: {{recipient.address}} <br/>
<img style="background: url(/pImages/{{recipient._id}}.jpg);"  />
```

IE seems to have a problem with the brackets in the style value
because the following hard-coded value works fine in IE

```
<img style="background: url(/pImages/230721.jpg);"  />
```

Every search I've done claims to resolve all of IE's issues by putting in
the shims, but I've done that.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work the same with all browsers:

```
<img [style.background-image]="'url(/pImages/' + recipient._id + '.jpg)'"  />
```

In Angular2 versions rc.x you currently need to sanitize some styles

See [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/s42OJ4HMTFwxeuhqlh6v?p=preview) and [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

In beta versions you don't need the pipe (`| safe`) I used in the Plunker.

Comment: That throws this error:  Cannot find a differ supporting object 'background-image:url(/pimages/57211a89b65ff1be3edd14c5.jpg);   I think its because ngStyle expects an ? :  expression.     Also img [style]="presetExpression" works fine EXCEPT in IE.   Still stuck.

Comment: The edited version doesn't work either, throws errors.

Comment: Wow...that fixed the problem in I.E.  Thanks !

Comment: FYI... I upgraded to RC1 which caused this solution to no longer work, so I tried using the sanitizer but that causes problems for styles that may have embedded single quotes.    This statement: sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(/pImages/' + this.recipientId + '.jpg)');

gets converted into this:

style="background-image: url("/pImages/57211a89b65ff1be3edd14c9.jpg");"

so the double quote right after url( ends the style string and breaks it.

I've tried manually putting in single quotes, but they end up getting converted to double quotes, breaking the style string.