# Angular2 RC1 Sanitizer inserts double quotes inside styles, breaking it

Tags: angular, styles, sanitization

I upgraded to RC1 which caused the previous solution for Beta 17 to no longer work, so I tried using the sanitizer but that causes problems for styles that may have embedded single quotes.

This statement:

```
sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(/pImages/' + this.recipientId + '.jpg)');
```

gets converted into this:

```
style="background-image: url("/pImages/57211a89b65ff1be3edd14c9.jpg");"
```

and the double quote mark right after url( ends the style string and breaks it.

So I tried manually inserting the single quote markers:

```
 sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url(\'/pImages/" + this.recipientId + ".jpg)\'");
```

But it converts those single quotes to double quotes and gives the same result, breaking the style string.

Comment: Interesting. Still working in Chrome though. I haven't found a way around. I'd consider this a bug. Can you please create an issue in http://github.com/angular/angular

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: Just did... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8664

Comment: Your pipe workaround in the plunkr works great, so I'll use that for now.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop, there is no code adding single or double quotes to URLs during sanitization, this was Chrome Dev Tools being misleading by displaying double quotes. I think the actual problem was that the URL wasn't correct, or something along those lines.