# Angular 2 - background image into a html file using ngStyle

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am pulling data from an API using an Angular 2 service.. I can output everything from the json api onto the page using something similar to this  {{ project.title }} however i wish to output the url to a background image and I cant seem to get it working.. has anyone got any ideas or advice ?

Currently this is what I have. I've tried it without the curly braces also but nothing is working.

```
<div class="table-wrap featuredimg"  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + {{ project.projectimage }} + ')'}">
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need use {{}} for call some propiety than you put in a directive, like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<div class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(' + object.link + ')'}"></div>
  `,
  styles: [`
  .image{width:100px;height:100px; border: solid 1px black;}
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedColor:any = 0;
  color;

  object = {
    link: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100"
  }

  constructor(){
  }
}
```

You can see the example in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3ze4fvZ3DiF4by9mdPr?p=preview). Enjoy.

Comment: Or just pass object to ngStyle like: `[ngStyle]="backgroundStyle"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `[]` and `{{}}` together, it's either the one or the other:

```
<div class="table-wrap featuredimg"  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + project.projectimage + ')'}">
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: still no joy with that.. it gives me undefined

Comment: Is it just me or is anybody else getting slightly disillusioned with Angular 2... it promises so much but even the most trivial of things requires so many steps to get right

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on top of Gunter's answer, this works with the async pipe as well.

```
 <div md-card-avatar class="profile_header" 
  [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + (usergravatar$ | async) + ')'}"></div>
```