# Owl Carousel is not working in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, owl-carousel

I am working on angular 4 and I want to implement owl carousel in my application. I imported owl carousel in the application refer by this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-owl-carousel.

But images is not coming. 
I am sharing in my code:

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {OwlCarousel} from 'ng2-owl-carousel';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
declare var $:any;
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    templateUrl:'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent{
    public pageTitle:string ='Home';
    @ViewChild('owlElement') owlElement: OwlCarousel       

      fun() {
        this.owlElement.next([200])
        //duration 200ms
      }
      object = {          
        link: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100"
      }

}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<owl-carousel
[options]="{items: 3, dots: false, navigation: false}"

[items]="images"

[carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
<div class="item" *ngFor="let image of images;let i = index">
    <div class="thumbnail-image" [ng-style]="{'background-image':'url(/assets/img/images.jpg)'}"></div>
</div>
</owl-carousel>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    OwlModule
]
```

[image]
Only next or prev is coming but Image is not coming. I am new in angular 4. So I am not able to solve this problem. I have seen links But Still I am not able to solve.

[angularjs ng-style: background-image isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252546/angularjs-ng-style-background-image-isnt-working)
[Angular 2 - background image into a html file using ngStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491166/angular-2-background-image-into-a-html-file-using-ngstyle)

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddler or plunker so that , can have better look into the issue

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any images inside your loop, add img inside your ngFor:

```
       <img src="{{image}}" style="" />
```

and use

```
      [ngStyle] and not [ng-style]
```

Answer (score 0):

have you included css and js as given in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel)

```
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js"
```

]

`"styles": [
    "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css",
    "../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css"
]`

2]don't use background images
use like below
    `

`

3. may be image url path may wrong
   [ng-style]="{'background-image':'url(/assets/img/images.jpg)'}"