# Angular dynamic background images

Tags: css, ipad, angular, styles

In the html template I have this style with a dynamic image:

```
<div style="background: url('/img/{{item.img}}'); width: 200px; height: 150px"></div>
```

Which works in web browsers and android browser. However background images that are dynamic using "style=" are not showing on iPad.

I could always create dynamic images using the img tag but I'm looking for a style/css solution for iPad.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use instead

```
<div [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(/img/' + item.img + ')', width: '200px', height: '150px'"></div>
```

or

```
<div [style.background]="'url(/img/' + item.img + ')'"
    [style.width.px]="200" [style.height.px]="150p"></div>
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37233523#37233523)

Comment: This works until you have an image that name contains brackets: some_image_(7).jpg

Comment: @wawka might be a browser problem, not an Angular problem https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=478139. Thanks for the info anyway. Others might run into that as well.

Comment: Nope. The same problem is on Chrome as well, which makes sense. Look how the background looks like `style="url(some_image_(7).jpg)"`. I guess you see where the problem is :) It causes the bracket closes too early.

Comment: Still not clear why this should be Angular related. Have you tried in plain CSS? Have you tried `style="url('some_image_(7).jpg')"`

Comment: This is an issue as you don't bind `style="url('some_image_(7).jpg')"` but `style="url(some_image_(7).jpg)"` (notice that there is no single quoted inside url).

Comment: Still not clear how this is related to this SO question/answer or Angular. What prevents you from adding the quotes to the string?

Comment: element.style.backgroundImage = \`url${image.url}\`

Answer (score 17):

You should do that as the +Günter Zöchbauer second part answer generates unwanted supplementary style background-position: initial and background-size: initial on Safari at least.

Note that I only set the background-image style:

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(/img/' + item.img + ')'"
 [style.width.px]="200" [style.height.px]="150p"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<div id="component-id" [style.background-image]="'url(www.domain.com/path/'+bgImageVariable+')'">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="component-id" [style.background-image]="'url('+bgImageVariable+')'">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

you can use in second way by adding URL path in a single variable.
for example

```
bgImageVariable="www.domain.com/path/img.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

use this and set height and width of div tag as per you need

```
<div id="component-id" [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+bgImageVariable+')'"></div>
```