# angular 4 style background image when using ngFor

Tags: javascript, css, json, angular

I have problem with background image url.
i have array have images url how can I use it in background image url

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let course of courses"><a>
    </a><div class="box"><a>
        <div class="box-gray aligncenter"  [style.backgroundColor]="course.imageUrl" >
        </div>
        </a><div class="box-bottom"><a >
            </a><a >{{course.name}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + course.imageUrl + ')'}"`

Comment: Ishnark has the correct answer

Answer (score 64):

Refer to this one [Angular2 dynamic background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575368/angular2-dynamic-background-images)

```js
// inappropriate style.backgroundColor 
[style.backgroundColor]="course.imageUrl"

// style.backgroundImage
[style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ course.imageUrl +')'"
```

Answer (score 16):

thank you for your answers,
the correct code is

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(' + course.imageUrl + ')'}">
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use `background` instead of `backgroundColor`

```
[style.background]="'url('+course.imageUrl+')'"
```

Comment: Nice i dont know why but if i use *style.backgroundImage* i does not update after the first value change but *background* it works fine jsut have to sanitize the url first

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by adding url path in a single variable.
for example

```
bgImageVariable="www.domain.com/path/img.jpg";
```

and

```
second way
```

> ```
> [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + bgImageVariable + ')'}"
> ```