# How to use style for background image in cloudinary tags?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angular2.
I want to use the the `style="backgroound-image : url("the url from the cloudinary")"`

**page.html**

```
<div>
<cl-image public-id = xyz.jpg>  


<cl-image>
<div>
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575368/angular2-dynamic-background-images

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with URL manipulation, e.g. in your css/scss file use:

```js
background-image: url('path-to-cloudinary-image')
```