# How to define multiple styles on div in .html template Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css-selectors

I need to set this properties on my div:

```
background: url();
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center, center;
```

This is my div:

```
<div *ngFor="let orderItems of receiptItems;" class="order-article animated bounceInLeft">
  <div class="order-img"   [style.background]="'url('+ orderItems.product.img.url +')'" ></div>
  <div class="order-title">
    <p>{{orderItems.product.title}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see guys I've set `[style.background] url` but I don't know how to set rest of the attributes / multiple attributes..

Thanks
Any kind of help would be great !

-------- EDIT:

```
 <div *ngFor="let orderItems of receiptItems;" class="order-article animated bounceInLeft">
      <div class="order-img"   [ngStyle]="{'background':'url('+ orderItem.product.imgUrl +')', 'background-repeat':' no-repeat','background-size': 'cover;','background-position': 'center, center' }" ></div>
      <div class="order-title">
        <p>{{orderItems.product.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

using ngStyle caused this:

[image]

attributes are not applied properly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 dynamic background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575368/angular2-dynamic-background-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `ngStyle` tag

```
<div   [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url( orderItem.product.imgUrl )', 'background-repeat':' no-repeat','background-size': 'cover','background-position': 'center, center' }"  class="order-img"  ></div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bqagz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Why did you change background to background-image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> **CSS**

```
.order-img{
background: url(--content);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center, center;
}
```

> **HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let orderItems of receiptItems;" class="order-article animated bounceInLeft">
  <div class="order-img" [attr.outage-count]="orderItems.product.img.url" ></div>
  <div class="order-title">
    <p>{{orderItems.product.title}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```