# change background image in angular

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to programmatically change the background image in angular.

```
this.document.getElementsByClassName("modal-header email-header")[0].style= 'background-image=""
```

It does not seem to work.

Comment: It would be better to avoid document query and instead apply it directly on the component. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37575497/15439733

Answer (score 1):

In angular we use variables in .ts and [bind](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax) the variables in the .html. So you can declare a variable in your .ts

```
background:string="assets/img.jpg"
```

And in .html

```
   <div class=""modal-header email-header" 
      [style.background-image]="background">
```

When in .ts you change the variable (I imagine in a function or in an event)

```
   this.background=null; //in any place
```

The "style.background-image" change in .html

NOTE: Instead use [style.background-image], you can also use [[ngStyle]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) or [[ngClass]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

NOTE2: I always suggest make a [tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) when we start with Angular or beings with [Getting started with Angular](https://angular.io/start)