# angular 2 - click function not working inside the popover

Tags: angular, bootstrap-popover

I am using a bootstrap popover with angular 2. Inside the popover the (click) function is not working.

Anyone know the solution.

Comment: please show your template code

Comment: This isn't enough information for anyone to figure out a solution. If you would please use a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) or paste in some of your code we would be able to help much better.

Answer (score 1):

If you add HTML string to the DOM using `[innerHTML]` or add it dynamically by other means, Angular2 expressions like bindings or component and directive selectors are **not** processed by Angular2 in any way and just added as-is to the DOM.

You can query the element after it was added and add an event listener imperatively.

See also [Angular 2 innerHTML (click) binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding/37676847#37676847)