# how to add html with click content to a component in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

html:

```
<ion-content padding>
<div [innerHTML]="bookContent"></div>
</ion-content>
```

ts:

```
  private bookContent: string = '<p>    this is a <a class="point"  (click)="pointClick(16)">point</a>, click to detail page.</p>';
  pointClick(id){
    this.navCtrl.push(PointPage, {pointId:id});
  }
```

The click event doesn't work.
In the developer tool, I found 'click' isn't exist.
[no click in the 'a' element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoXys.png)

what should i do to achieve this function.

Comment: angular 2 doesnt really allow that..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding

Comment: thank you for your suggest.Can i use elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('a') ,and renderer.invokeElementMethod(element, 'click', []);?