# click action in an innerhtml using angular4 not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to put an anchor tag in an innerHTML and I am using angular 4.

```
in HTML file: <div [innerHTML]="'myText' | translate">

in Component: const myText = "mytext go here and <a (click)='myFunction()'> click here </a>."
```

I am not getting the "(click)='myFunction()'" inside  in the DOM.

Comment: What are you getting? also, you are telling `[innerHTML]` to interpret `'myText'`as a string because it is wrapped in single quotes

Comment: `'myText' | translate`  should be changed to: `myText | translate`

Comment: @Derek it should be `myText | translate` because `translate` here is pipe

Comment: @PardeepJain I stand corrected, my apologies

Comment: @Derek I am getting the translated html, but there is no click event. I mean on click nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work, your code is fine but it's by design of Angular.

Whenever you pass some content via `innerHTML`, Angular is just going to render that content does not evaluate any `expression` or `binding`  within that content like you did by adding a click event.

So In order to achieve this (as per your requirement), you can wrap your content into another component and pass data via `@input` property binding and display it into the browser.

For more detail you can read out here -

- [Angular 2 innerHTML (click) binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding)

Comment: That's very sad to hear. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @KRUSHANUMOHAPATRA No worries man, There are number of ways to solve one problem :)

Comment: We just can use 'pointer-events: none;' in CSS for the div with innerHTML.