# InnerHTML *ngIf does not work Angular5

Tags: angular, innerhtml, angular-ng-if

To show a pop up on a GIS openlayers map i use the InnerHtml attribute.
If a field is false I want to hide is DIV.

It looks like angular ignores my ngif this is my code:

```
this.content.innerHTML = `
      <div style="width: 150px; float: right; font-size: 13px;" *ngIf="!test">
              ${ test } 
      </div> `
```

My boolean test is false. Is it true that ngIf does niet work with innerHTML?

thx al lot

Comment: Yes, it is true. You would have to compile the HTML, which is not possible in a prod build, where you don't want to ship the template compiler with your app. If you're doing HTML in your TypeScript code: something is wrong. If you use innerHTML, something is generally wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809363/click-action-in-an-innerhtml-using-angular4-not-working/50809586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular will not entertain your `*ngIf` when you are using `innerHTML`

Whenever you pass some content via innerHTML, Angular is just going to render that content does not evaluate any expression or binding within that content like you did by adding a `ngIf` event.

Comment: is there an other way to make *ngif possobible in a popover?

Comment: Simply you can check before assigning by varible `test`

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and remove the styles like below

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { 

 this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#showResponsiveNavbarone')
 .classList.remove('visibletrue');

}
 <style>
  .visiblefalse{
  display: none !important;
}
.visibletrue{
 display: block !important;
}
```