# Angular 5 and jQuery: (click) not calling function

Tags: jquery, angular

I am currently working with Angular 5 and jQuery. I created a dynamic div through jQuery which I appended to a div.

```
var push_div = '<div class="col-md-6">
                <span style="color: green;">' + 
                droppedItemID + '</span>&nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                (click)="removeContent()">X</a>
                </div>'
$(push_div).hide().appendTo("#" + dropZoneID).fadeIn(1000);
```

When I click on the link, the `removeContent` function is not calling.

```
removeContent() {
    console.log("function called");
}
```

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: <a id="myLink" href="javascript:MyFunction();">link text</a>
or
<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="MyFunction();">link text</a> ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick

Comment: @King If I used onclick, then it shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: removeContent is not defined`

Comment: <a [routerLink]="" (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a>
or <button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button> ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639174/passive-link-in-angular-2-a-href-equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design. Angular does not handle bindings defined in strings such as `innetHTML` bindings. `(click)` binding will not be processed in your situation.

You can do it like:

```js
var dropZoneID = 'dropZone'
var droppedItemID = 'droppedItemID'

function removeContent() {
  console.log('removeContent');
}

var push_div = '<div class="col-md-6"><span style="color: green;">' + droppedItemID + '</span>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)">X</a></div>'
$(push_div).hide().appendTo("#" + dropZoneID).fadeIn(1000);

// Using $(document).on(...) to bind events to dynamically created elements
$(document).on('click', $(push_div).find('a').eq(0), function() {
  removeContent()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropZone"></div>
```

For further details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676847/1331040

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809586/1331040

Comment: I did like `$(push_div).click(function(){ this.removeContent() });` but it did not work. Can you please look into it again.

Comment: I updated the answer and added a snippet. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this -> `href="javascript:void(0)"` from `<a>` tag.