# Making Angular 6 aware of code in real time

Tags: angular

Given the following `innerHtml` statement in a template:

```
<div [innerHtml]="content"></div>
```

and the following code in the component:

```
this.content = '<a href (click)="clickMe()">Click Me</a>;'

clickMe(){
    alert('link was clicked');
}
```

Clicking on the link does nothing, as the anchor is not compiled. How to make Angular aware of the `(click)` event? In AngularJS I used `$compile` but I couldn't find an equivalent in Angular 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 innerHTML (click) binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding)