# How to fix function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add tree button items from my database table to my drop down menu, but the onclick event doesnt call the function being passed. Here is the error I am getting upon clicking the button. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
addFormatItemHandler() 
{
    var self = this;

    this.m_tree.formatItem.addHandler
    (
        function(p_sender, p_event) 
        {
            var item = p_event.dataItem;

                    p_event.element.innerHTML = "<button onclick='myFunction()'></button>";                                 

        }
    );

}

myFunction(){

console.log("My function");

}
```

Expected result:
My function

Actual result:
myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 0):

As long as you put the word `function` before your function it should work if you're doing it like the following example:

```js
function addFormatItemHandler() {
  var self = this;

  this.m_tree.formatItem.addHandler(
    function(p_sender, p_event) {
      var item = p_event.dataItem;
      p_event.element.innerHTML = "<button onclick='myFunction()'></button>";
    }
  );
}

function myFunction() {
  console.log("My function");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">My button</button>
```

Comment: it works like this way but when I dynamically add my button through innerHTML, it doesnt work.

Comment: Your innerHTML might be wrong `<button onclick='myFunction()'>" + item.header + "</a>` I don't know if that item.header closes the button and opens an `<a>`  tag

Comment: I have updated my code. Item.header was only the header name.

Comment: I don't know what else can be wrong, if you're still having troubles can you make a small example on https://stackblitz.com/ and maybe there I can see if there's anything wrong

Comment: Pnadalini, I was able to fix that. Thanks for your help. Mitchapp post from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding helped me to fix my issue.