# Angular add (click) event to dynamic HTML <a> tag?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and trying to figure out a solution to this problem. In my .ts file I have string like  `var info = "Please Download File" + "<a (click)=downloadFile()>Click Here</a>`. The anchor tag is dynamically added inside a function.I am trying to fire downloadFile() function but not sure how to solve this problem? When I inspect the element it does not show (click) function

Comment: It's better to generate your html in the template, instead of in javascript. For example, you could have a `mylinks` array that contains all your urls, and then display that array in the template using `<a ngFor="let link of mylinks" (click)="download()">click me</a>` as in this example: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Kokodoko that there is probably a better way to accomplish what you want. However, if you want to inject HTML you will need to Sanitize it and use `innerHtml`. For example in your typescript file you will need to do something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public info = "Please Download File" + "<a (click)=downloadFile()>Click Here</a>"


  safeHtml(html) {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

and in your HTML

`<div [innerHTML]="safeHtml(info)"></div>`

I created a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6rnmni) that you can play with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i should have added more info on my question. info will be assigned to the property of custom element. For e.g the the already predefined custom element looks like:

<my-notify>
[message]
[type]
</mynotify>
I was thinking of assigning info to message

Comment: I added downloadFile() function to StackBlitz example but it's not doing anything. Can you suggest?

Comment: That is a bit of a different conundrum indeed. Perhaps take a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676847/6335049). That may get you started down the right path.

Comment: Can you help me figuring out why downloadFile() function is not being called in StackBlitz example?