# Anchor tag in Json to HTML

Tags: angular

Sup, guys...

I have a json files with lot of texts for internationalize my app. In some lines I need to put anchor tags. My **problem** is when json renders into HTML, anchor tag is not working properly. As you may see, I have a (click)="switchPage('something)' in my anchor tag and when I open the page where is the html code I got this on the console: **WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see http://g.co/ng/security#xss**. But if I change the (click) for href="something" it works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance anyway!

**JSON Line**

```
"instructions": "Already a member? <a (click)='switchPage('signIn')>Sign-In now!</a>",
```

**Pipe**

```
export class SanitizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform (value: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value));
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <p class="mat-small bit-of-space" id="result" [@vanish]="page" [innerHTML]="'login.pages.'+page+'.instructions' | translate | sanitizeHTML"></p>
```

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676847/1009922), the Angular bindings contained in the HTML content inserted with `[innerHTML]` will not be honored.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks, mate. I'll try it and let you know. Appreciated!