# Why isn't the function being called? (in the Ionic & Angular Framework)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image]

This is the code, it's using the DOM Selector in the Ionic & Angular Framework. I'm unsure why the `console.log` of "placing order" does not display when the button is clicked. I tried to use many alternatives like `ngClick`, `ng-click`, `ngclick` or changing the syntax of the function to `this.placeOrder()`, `placeOrder = () => {}`, etc but all did not work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using angular 2+ or angular js version? Please post a reproducable code snippet.

Comment: @Nitheesh here is a snippet of the code. 
 
var x = document.getElementById("elementToReplace");
  x.innerHTML = 
'<ion-button (click)="placeOrder()" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 2px; margin-left: 40px;" >Place Order</ion-button>'


placeOrder() {
    console.log("placing order");
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 innerHTML (click) binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding)

Comment: @Nitheesh not really because its actually replacing the whole ion-content element. And i understand it's frowned upon but i wasn't using the Ref method instead just the js DOM selector method. All the other functions are working but just not the clicking of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a listener of clicking event to the `ion-button`:

```js
x.querySelector('ion-button').addEventListener('click', () => this.placeOrder());
```

Working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/inner-html-event