# Inline style background-image using ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to set the background image for each div in an ngFor loop. In the JSON I'm looping over I have a property `property.Image` that holds a url string to an image. `<img src={{flag.properties.Image}}/>` works, but my attempt to show the image as a background-image does not. In the browser Inspector the div background-image shows as {{flag.properties.Image}} rather than reading the url that I'm trying to point to. What am I doing wrong?

```
<h3>Top Flags</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <div *ngFor="let flag of flags" (click)="gotoDetail(flag)" class="col-1-4">
    <div class="module flag" style="background-image: url({{flag.properties.Image}})">
      <h4>{{flag.id}}</h4>
      <div><img src={{flag.properties.Image}} height="50px" /></div>
      <div>{{flag.properties.Adaptation}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use instead

```ts
[style.background-image]="'url('+flag.properties.Image+')'"
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: I ended up creating a custom pipe like you suggested in your linked answer. It worked!

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary with RC.2 anymore.