# unsafe value used in a resource URL context when loading local css file

Tags: angular, sanitization

I wonder if anyone can explain the meaning of the Dom Sanitisation in Angular2 in my case:

The img case is fine, it just werks. The stylesheet will trigger an error like in the title.
What the what? Why? Anyone?

```
<img *ngIf="css" [src]="css" style="height:64px;margin-right:8px">
<link *ngIf="css" rel="stylesheet" [href]="css">
```

Comment: What does `css` contain?

Comment: /somename.css or ./somename.css or somename.css I tried all three options

Comment: I just updated to RC 3, it was working on RC 1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: Can you explain why it's safe for images and not css?

Comment: Also do you want to answer so I could accept? I used the pipe solution but it feels too much like a workaround in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update**

`DomSanitizationService` is going to be renamed to `DomSanitizer` in RC.6

**original**

Images are safe. There is an `<img>` tag and that displays the image data, that's it. CSS can do much more. CSS can even add HTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after which is quite insecure.

To explicitly allow "unsafe" content use the sanitizer

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
```

or use one of the other methods the sanitizer provides https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizationService-class.html

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076868/217408 for an example pipe that allows to apply the `bypassSecurityXxx` methods directly in bindings.