# Is there a safe workaround to Angular 2's style attribute sanitization?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm currently learning Angular 2, and I was attempting to load HTML with a style attribute from a property in the component.

```
items.push('<span style="color: ' + colorHex + ';">test</span>');

<div class="itemList" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <pre [innerHtml]=item></pre>
</div>
```

After doing some research it appears Angular 2 sanitizes style attributes to prevent security issues. Am I approaching this wrong? How else can I attach colors to text? I was using the `<font>` tag, but it's deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [style binding target](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)(search for 'style.' on the page)? It shows how to set individual style properties on your html element. For example here is a way to apply the color style you asked about.

```
<div class="itemList" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <pre [style.color]="colorHex">Test</pre>
</div>
```