# How to use HTML tags in interpolation syntax

Tags: angular

How can I use in interpolations HTML tags in HTML templates with Angular 2?

For example:

```
<h1> {{title ? title : '<i>Title not set</i>'}} </h1>
```

If the `title` is undefined then there should be a `Title not set` in `i`-Tags.

If I use the syntax above Angular will display exactly the expression (means with the {{, ?, :, }}) and does not evaluate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<h1 [innerHTML]="title ? title : '<i>Title not set</i>'"></h1>
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: Hi! Is this still valid for version 8? It still seems a hack to me.

Comment: I didn't follow Angular recently, but I guess it's still the same. It's usually not something you would need often.