# Angular 2 - Piping value and returning DOM element

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I am attempting to use a custom pipe to take in a int value and then return a material design icon based on that int.

HTML:

```
{{item.MetGoal | NumberToStatusSymbol}}
```

TypeScript/JS:

```
transform(value, args?) {
    switch (value){
        case '0':
            return $.parseHTML(`<i class="material-icons text-red">&#xE5C9;</i>;`);
        case '1':
            return $.parseHTML(`<i class="material-icons text-green">&#xE86C;</i>`);
        case '2':
            return $.parseHTML(`<i class="material-icons text-yellow">&#xE8B2;</i>`);
        default: break;
    }
}
```

However when the page loads its only showing [object HTMLElement] instead of the actual HTML element listed in the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div [outerHTML]="item.MetGoal | NumberToStatusSymbol"
```

`{{}}` does string interpolation and adds the result as string. This doesn't seem to be what you want.

You might need to do some sanitization. See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

```
case '0':
  return &#xE5C9;
...
```

with

```
<i class="material-icons">{{item.MetGoal | NumberToStatusSymbol}}</i>
```

might work, but then you have to use a different pipe for the `text-xxx` attribute.

Comment: This seems close, however the MD icon doesn't seem to respond correctly.  Instead of showing the icon it simply has the character text.

Comment: If MD icons are Angular components or directives this won't work (I haven't used Angular2 material myself) In this case you would need to create dynamic components like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Got it with the outerHTML attribute binding, thanks as usual Gunter.

Comment: The only odd thing is that with the switch applying the material design i tag with the included classes the color class (text-***) is added by the style isn't applied.

Comment: Hey Gunter, looks like one issue with this method is that the angular 2 attribute '_ngcontent***' is missing from the imported dom element.

Comment: I see. There is no way to get it applied to elements added dynamically. It might work with just passing the unicode value but not with passing the `<i...>` element.