# TypeScript - Append HTML to container element in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I want to do is simply to append some html on an element.
I checked some links and found different confusing, non-working, non-recommended solutions.

Using JavaScript, I'll do something like this:

```
var d1 = document.getElementsByClassName('one');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>');
```

How do I achieve the same result using typescript/angular2, RC5?

**EDIT**

The element with class `.one` is generated by an external js, and I can't modify it.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

1.

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
```

```
this.htmlToAdd = '<div class="two">two</div>';
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

2. Alternatively

```
<div class="one" #one></div>
```

```
@ViewChild('one') d1:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>');
}
```

or to prevent direct DOM access:

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {}

@ViewChild('one') d1:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.d1.nativeElement', 'insertAdjacentHTML' ['beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>']);
}
```

  3.

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var d1 = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.one');
  d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>');
}
```

Comment: `var d1 = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.one');` returns null :) I think it executes before it renders the html

Comment: This might be related to how you create the `.one` element. I don't have any information about that.

Comment: for some reason, ngAfterviewinit have to be like this:

setTimeout(() => { 
   var d1 = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.one');
    d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>');

   }, 1000);

Comment: @jcdsr you could try `ngAfterContentInit`. I don't remember which one executes first.

Comment: Does the 3rd solution too prevent Direct Dom Access?

Comment: No, it uses `nativeElement` but I think this is now considered Ok in contrary to back then when I posted the answer. Only if you want to use server-side rendering or webworker then you need to avoid it.

Comment: what if the div I want to manipulate is added at runtime? that is, I am adding a span to the dom manually using insertAdjacentHTML and then I am trying to change its content but nothing is happening

Comment: @Gunter, Can I add some angular component as below
this.htmlToAdd = '<app-trendline [data]="dbData" [locked]="locked" [id]="'id1'"></app-trendline>

Comment: @ashishkumar No, just plain HTML. There is information out there abour what you want like https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576727/angular-compile-and-create-components-at-runtime

Answer (score 30):

With the new angular class [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer2) {}

  @ViewChild('one', { static: false }) d1: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const d2 = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const text = this.renderer.createText('two');
    this.renderer.appendChild(d2, text);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.d1.nativeElement, d2);
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

**htmlComponent.ts**

`htmlVariable: string = "<b>Some html.</b>";` //this is html in TypeScript code that you need to display

**htmlComponent.html**

`<div [innerHtml]="htmlVariable"></div>` //this is how you display html code from TypeScript in your html

Comment: My content is generated by an JS, which I cannot modify, and therefore cannot use [innerHtml]

Comment: <div [innerHtml]="htmlVariable"></div> - this works if htmlVariable is native html tags, but how to render custom tags? like <div [innerHtml]="htmlVariable"></div> where htmlVariable is '<my-custom-selector></my-custom-selector>? any Idea?

Comment: @Stefan Svrkota`htmlVariable: string = "<b *ngIf='somevar=true'>Some html.</b>";` if i use ngIf will it work

Answer (score 5):

There is a better solution to this answer that is more Angular based.

1. Save your string in a variable in the .ts file

   `MyStrings = ["one","two","three"]`
2. In the html file use *ngFor.

   `<div class="one" *ngFor="let string of MyStrings; let i = index">
        <div class="two">{{string}}</div>
    </div>`
3. if you want to dynamically insert the div element, just push more strings into the MyStrings array

   `myFunction(nextString){
       this.MyString.push(nextString)
    }`

this way every time you click the button containing the myFunction(nextString) you effectively add another class="two" div which acts the same way as inserting it into the DOM with pure javascript.

Comment: eg. MyStrings = ["<div class='my-class'>This is starting", "some dynamic text<br><br> ", "...this is ending</div>";

When we loop through it in the html, angular is auto closing the first <div> and then the last </div> is kind of broken. Another example is if we have some table and td tags in the array opening and closing so we can create the table structure dynamically and add the dynamic text.

Output: <div class='my-class'>This is starting</div> some dynamic text this is ending</div>

Expected output: <div class='my-class'> some dynamic text ...this is ending</div>

Answer (score 2):

When working with Angular the recent update to Angular 8 introduced that a `static` property inside `@ViewChild()` is required as stated [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration). Then your code would require this small change:

```
@ViewChild('one') d1:ElementRef;
```

into

```
// query results available in ngOnInit
@ViewChild('one', {static: true}) foo: ElementRef;
```

OR

```
// query results available in ngAfterViewInit
@ViewChild('one', {static: false}) foo: ElementRef;
```