# Angular, compile and create components at runtime

Tags: angular, dynamic, compile-time

I'm trying to make a document generation tool in angular and I'm hitting a challenge with how I would allow a user to dynamically create content.

My components I want to create could have arbitrary models and behavior so I don't think I could use a shared component.

The components I'm describing would not exist at compile time.

I see some [documentation for rendering dynamic components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). However it mentions that you must list the "dynamic" component in `entryComponents` in the `ngModule`. which **will not work** for my scenario.

> Is there another mechanism to get this effect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a module and a component on-the-fly, apply decorators to it and then compile it all. Then you will be able to access the compiled components:

```
@ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
            private _injector: Injector,
            private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const template = '<span>generated on the fly: {{name}}</span>';

  const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {
  });
  const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
  });

  this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
    .then((factories) => {
      const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
      const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
      cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
      this.vc.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
    })
}
```

For this approach to work you need to bring compiler to the runtime. For more details on dynamic components read the article:

- [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the info. Do you happen to know how will this change for angular 8/ivy ? I beliave you now can have both AOT for your core and JIT for code generated on the fly

Comment: @user5328504, it's still unclear. We need to wait a little for this information until Ivy is released

Comment: In Angular8 I do get the error message "Error: Runtime Compiler not loaded", when calling _compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync_ in your code. Any clue?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi, now Ivy is here, is it possible to give a direction on the question of @user5328504?

Comment: I would love that @MaxKoretskyi

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi fast forward 2022/Angular 13. How to compile component on the fly with Ivy? I am able to create a component using the function viewContainerRef.createComponent(myComponent), however it does not load FormsModule/CommonModule etc.

Comment: @U.P, haven't explored that yet, I will at some point

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi How do I do this now that Compiler has been deprecated?

Comment: That link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I find out solution that works with Angular 13, and want to share with you.

```
const importedFile = await import('pathToModule');
const module: NgModuleRef<E> = createNgModuleRef<E>(importedFile[moduleClassName], this._injector);
this.containerRef.createComponent(importedFile[componentClassName], { ngModuleRef: module });
```

In Angular 13 the `Compiler` is depracated. The entire compilation process is done under the hood, even if we dynamically import some module/component.

My solution require add an export with component we want to create in the imported module file.

```
export * from './containers/container.component';
```

**Instead of importing file you can create component and modules on the fly (like example above) but instead of compiler use just `createNgModuleRef` and `createComponent` functions **

Comment: Piotr, this is very interesting, can you expand on how to dynamically create component from a template string?

Comment: While creating component on fly, can implements "OnInit, AfterViewInit" be added?