# document setAttribute ngModel Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying create an input element from typescript to html in angular 4. But when I try put `[(ngModel)]` not works. How I do that method ? Someone know how ?

```
createElement() {
    this.input = document.createElement('input');
    this.input.setAttribute('matInput', '');
    this.input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Tema');
    this.input.setAttribute('[(ngModel)]', 'module.theme');
    this.input.setAttribute('name', 'theme');

    return (<HTMLDivElement>(document.getElementById('ejemplo').appendChild(this.input)));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
 this.input.setAttribute('[(ngModel)]', 'module.theme');
```

is not supposed to work.
Property/attribute bindings and component/directive instantiation only happens for markup added to a components template statically.

If it is added dynamically it won't have any effect.
If you need this, you can create and compile a component at runtime and add that component dynamically (to a statically defined `ViewContainerRef`).

Alternatively you can use imperative code to update the DOM.

Comment: And how to do the "create and compile a component" thing?

Comment: The link in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46578036/217408 seems to be recent enough. There are several other related questions/answers on SO.

Comment: Thanks, but that creates the component from a html string, not from a HTMLElement object. Would be possible without calling .innerHTML? And how to do it in a directive (having access only to the ElementRef and not ViewContainerRef)?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this topic. I never used it myself.