# Angular dynamic template loading

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

we have a requirement to load angular templates dynamically at runtime from DB through a rest API call. I know it is possible using JIT compiler but it is not recommended in newer angular versions ( from angular 9 onwards) . Can this be achieved using AOT compiler ? or Do we have any workaround for this like SSR or any other technique ?

Comment: Technically you can with Ivy by bundling in the compiler. But I don’t think it is recommend and you need to use private API’s for it that might break in future versions..

Comment: Thanks ... can you refer to an article ?

Comment: There are some hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576727/angular-compile-and-create-components-at-runtime