# Render an Angular string template at runtime

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have a component that makes a request to fetch an Angular template from the server and render it at runtime. Please keep in mind that the template is an Angular formatted template using Angular pipes and directives, so it's not something like using lodash templates. A very simple example of this template would be:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item.name | titlecase }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my component I've tried doing the following that excludes actually fetching the template from the server for my example for simplicity sake:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="template"></div>`,
})
export class LandingPageComponent {
  @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(DynamicTemplateComponent);
    componentRef.instance.items = [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' }, { name: 'baz' }];
    componentRef.instance.template = `<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item.name | titlecase }}
      </li>
    </ul>`;
  }
}
```

And here is the `DynamicTemplateComponent` that is used to create the component to dynamically render the Angular template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-template',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="template"></div>`,
})
export class DynamicTemplateComponent {
  @Input() template: string;
  @Input() items: any[];
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't produce any results. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dynamic components with a custom template and any other properties.

In this case if you want to dynamically change decorated properties on a component creation then it needs to be manually compiled async. Please check the example below:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const template = `<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</div>`;
    const component = getComponentFromTemplate(template);

    const componentRef = this.viewRef.createComponent(component);
    componentRef.setInput('items', ['value1', 'value2']);
  }
```

```
@Component({
    template: '',
  }) class MyCustomComponent {
    @Input() items: string[] = [];
}

function getComponentFromTemplate(template: string) {
  ɵcompileComponent(MyCustomComponent, {
    template,
    standalone: true,
    imports: [NgFor],
  });

  return MyCustomComponent;
}
```

And there is example on stackblitz: [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6ehko?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: This is excellent, however, I'm using Angular 13.0.0 and it appears that "standalone" isn't recognized. Would I just need to register my component in the declarations within feature's module?

Comment: For older versions: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nnkt3a?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576727/angular-compile-and-create-components-at-runtime

Comment: Someone have already tried using material components in the template? It seems it doesn't work at runtime. Any solutions? My test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpmp2a

Comment: Don't you forget add all needed material modules to imports?

Comment: I don't think so. If you check the stackblitz, they're already there

Comment: You haven't completed your project configuration for Angular Material. You should add icons as font to the project. Add into the `head` tag link: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @AlexGreg see my answer