# Is there a way to render Angular template on runtime?

Tags: angular, jit, angular-template

I'm using `Angular 16.0.3` and I'm trying to make a component that receives a template string and render it at runtime. The template string can contain Angular components in it and will probably be fetched from a server.

I based myself on this StackOverflow question: [Render an Angular string template at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883000/render-an-angular-string-template-at-runtime).

**I tried this:**

*dynamic-template.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ɵcompileComponent } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-dynamic-template',
template: '\<ng-container #container\>\</ng-container\>'
})
export class DynamicTemplateComponent {
@Input() content: string
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef

constructor() {}

generate(): void {
const component = getComponentFromTemplate(this.content)
this.container.clear();
const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(component);
console.log(componentRef)
}
}

@Component({
template: '',
}) class TemplateComponent {
@ViewChild('heading') heading: HTMLHeadingElement
}

function getComponentFromTemplate(template: string) {
ɵcompileComponent(TemplateComponent, {
template,
standalone: true,
});

return TemplateComponent;
}
```

**But I'm getting this:**

*Console*

```
JIT compilation failed for component class TemplateComponent {}
ERROR Error: The component 'TemplateComponent' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider using AOT mode instead.
Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
at getCompilerFacade (core.mjs:5088:15)
at TemplateComponent.get \[as ɵcmp\] (core.mjs:24683:34)
at getComponentDef (core.mjs:1839:16)
at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.mjs:23218:31)
at DynamicHtmlComponent.generate (dynamic-html.component.ts:16:41)
at GuestComponent.generate (guest.component.ts:16:27)
at GuestComponent_Template_button_click_3_listener (guest.component.html:3:20)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:15700:16)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15733:22)
at HTMLButtonElement.\<anonymous\> (platform-browser.mjs:666:17)
```

**My Questions**

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is there a way to make only one lazy loaded child module to use the JIT compiler and if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: If you want to host your HTML on a server and render it on demand, then Angular is probably not the framework you're looking for. Stop trying to cater it to your needs, and instead use it as it is intended !

Answer (score 0):

In your angular.json file, under architect:build.options, add/set "aot":false

As per various documentation, it is not recommended to use in production.