# HTML not interpreted in Angular template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

It has been several days since I am stuck on a problem that I do not see where it can come from.

I currently retrieve the content of my article in an observable and I loop over it in the angular template. So far I have no problem I get my information well that I display but the HTML is not interpreted with an innerHTML, nor with a pipe using the DomSanitizer.

I tried to store the information of my observable in a table to see if it does not come from the asynchronous but no.

I saw that it was necessary to use the DomSanitizer to force the security because when the string that contains the HTML is too long (which is my case because it is long paragraphs), the innerHTML has not no effect.

The string fits well in my pipe because when I make a console.log of my variable containing the string, it shows me well in my console with HTML tags around.

If you have any idea where my problem may come from, knowing that I have no errors in the console.

Here is my code without the pipe and HTML not interpreted :

```
<div *ngFor="let article of informationsArticle|async;">

      <div [innerHTML]="article.contenu_part1" *ngIf="article.contenu_part1"></div>

</div>
```

With the pipe and HTML not interpreted:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of informationsArticle|async;">

      <p [innerHTML]="article.contenu_part1 | keepHtml" *ngIf="article.contenu_part1"></p>

</div>
```

The pipe code :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

I added it in "declarations" of app.module.ts file as well as its import at the top of the file.

Rendering the source code in the console :

[image]

Comment: Angular processes only HTML added to a components template **statically**. HTML added by `innerHTML` will be added as is. Angular won't even look at it except for sanitization to prevent XSS.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is to say ? What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular or just do not use bindings in dynamically added HTML. You could modify the content imperatively before adding it to the DOM.

Comment: If I take the second solution that you propose to me, that is to say that I must remove my pipe and the innerHTML in the template and use nativeElement.innerHTML in the typescript ? Like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126327/8248966 ?

Comment: I didn't see the actual problem at first. I assumed you wanted to use Angular-specific markup in the dynamically added HTML. Just adding plain HTML should work with `[innerHTML]="..."` binding. There has to be something else that goes wrong. Perhaps `article.contenu_part1` already returns an encoded string?

Comment: content_part1 is a string that contains HTML tags with text

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproduction in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: It's very difficult to create a minimal a reproduction because there is a lot of dependence, can I send you my project by mail or use TeamViewer ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not interested in a complicated project. You should be able to reproduce with a few lines. No need to add any code of your project except what you already posted in your question. Just demonstrate how `[innerHTML]="..."` does not render the passed HTML.

Comment: Ok, I try that.

Comment: It works if I create a string variable in https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6vjpzf .. I don't understand why .. In my real project, I make an http request that I get in an observable and I loop above

Comment: I guess it's up to you to figure out where the difference is. Sorry, but there is no way to do it from here if you can't provide a reproduction.

Comment: I can not provide replication because it is not possible to make an http request in stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6vjpzf

Comment: You don't need to drag in the world to get a reproduction. You can just copy the text your HTTP request returns and copy it into the stackblitz example. You'll have to examine bit for bit until you find where the difference is that causes your behavior. That's what software developers do ;-)

Comment: that's what I did, I copied / pasted the string returned by my http request and assigned it to a variable

Comment: Your stackblitz doesn't seem to use the `keepHtml` pipe you demonstrate in your question.

Comment: because basically it does not work with only an innerHTML, except that yes there

Comment: The short string is interpreted but not the long string

Comment: I updated your stackblitz with your pipe and `Observable.of()` function to imitate HTTP response, seems to work properly, also added some inline style: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tag2dg?file=pages/home/home.ts

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with your HTTP response processing. Could you share relevant to HTTP call/response code?