# Iframe code is converting into a dom object when binding from Angular component to HTML template

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular2-template

I am working on a project based on Angular 2. I got stuck in one problem. I am dealing with Iframe. In my angular component, I am generating an Iframe as:

```
    this.ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    console.log(title_colorr);
    this.ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://web.com/newsfeed/");
    this.ifrm.style.width = widthh + "px";;
    this.ifrm.style.height = heightt + "px";
```

I am getting a full Iframe code when I am putting

`console.log(this.ifrm);` as:
﻿

```
<iframe src="http://web.com/newsfeed/" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"></iframe>
```

Now the problem is when I am trying to use this in my HTML template as:

`<p >{{ifrm}}</p>` then I am getting :

> [object HTMLIFrameElement]

I have used `<p [innerHTML]="ifrm"></p>` too, but no solution is there.

Is there anybody, who knows how to solve this?

Comment: Please check this, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832358/angular-5-how-to-insert-a-string-as-a-html-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832358/angular-5-how-to-insert-a-string-as-a-html-element)

Comment: @Shantanu thank you for the answer but it isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import ElementRef and Renderer2 from '@angular/core' and change your constructor to

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }
```

Now you can use appendChild function of renderer as follows:

```
this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.ifrm);
```

In your html file you can just have

```
<p></p>
```

And it should work.