# Css white-space: pre-line not working as expected

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

```js
content: string;
this.content = "The system was unable to process your request.<br/>Please use your browser back button.";
```

```css
.content{
 white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body text-center">
  <span class="content">
   {{ content }}
  </span>
</div>
```

pre-line is supposed to break in 
 tags, instead, I get the full message including the tag. I've already tried with \n and 
 but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is the problem that you are seeing the `<br/>` tag as part of the text? If so, css has nothing to do with it

Comment: pre-line
Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Comment: Are you using angular ? In that case you could pass as innerHTML to display html content.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4

Comment: @Ted yes this is the problem, why do you say css has nothing to do with it?

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy Yes I am using Angular. In the post you linked they are saying that this is considered unsafe from angular.

Comment: @A.Ashley your trouble is in converting a `string` to `html`

Comment: @A.Ashley Take a look at this question/answer: [Angular 5 How to insert a string as a HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832358/angular-5-how-to-insert-a-string-as-a-html-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals in your typescript to pass a multi-line string. This will keep the line breaks in the text but requires to replace the `<br>` tag with a simple line break.

```js
this.content = `The system was unable to process your request.
Please use your browser back button.`;
```