# JQuery .replaceWith Angular2 content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, replacewith

I am working on a project using both JQuery and Angular2 in order to use a JQuery library.

My problem is when it comes to replace DOM element with Angular2 code using JQuery.

I am expecting the below code to add Angular code in the DOM element:

```
let myContainer = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(".question-text");
myContainer.innerHTML = "<span>{{model?.text}}</span>";
```

What it does instead, is to replace the innerHTML setting the `{{model?.text}}` as a string and not as a dynamic content.

Is there a way to achieve it? Any help is welcome

Comment: if you want to add dynamic element you can use renderer2 angular service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find a Solution here: [TypeScript - Append HTML to container element in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126299/typescript-append-html-to-container-element-in-angular-2)

I would suggest to use `ngIf` and set a flag if you want to render your content, so you actually need no jQuery for it.

Comment: thank you for the effort, I tried your solutions but unfortunately the result is the same - it parses the `{{model?.text}}` as a string and not as a dynamic content. The *ngIf approach looks more suitable though. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to something like `$compile( "<span>{{model?.text}}</span>" )( $scope );`
Inject `$compile` before that