# new line in tooltip while unsing ngx-translate

Tags: html, angular, tooltip, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate.

How can I put a line break in a standard html tooltip to translate ?

In my template I have :

```
<div [title]="'TOOLTIP_STRING' | translate">hover here</div>
```

In my en.json:

```
{
"TOOLTIP_STRING": "Tooltiptext&#13;Another line etc etc.&#13;Text on second line"
}
```

I tried `\n <br/> <br>` Nothing works. If I make the text static (just type it in the html) it works fine.

Comment: have you tried `<br>` ?

Comment: Yes, I also mentioned it in my question

Comment: you could try to [try to use innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126299/typescript-append-html-to-container-element-in-angular-2) , this way your string will be interpreted as HTML and your `br` will be correctly recognized.

Comment: InnerHtml is for rendering the inner HTML/The content inside the div. I need a new line in the tooltip.