# Insert XML into DOM in Angular 2

Tags: xml, templates, dom, angular

I'm fairly new to Angular 2 and am really having a hard time trying to figure out how to add XML to my html template. I would like to conditionally insert specific sets of XML into my template from which an external library renders some SVG. I have my XML sets as js strings which I'm trying to interpolate in my template.

UPDATE:

I've got some XML as a string that would I like to display in a template.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
const xml = 'valid xml string';
```

in component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "toolbox",
  template: `{{xml}}` <-- gives me xml as a string into DOM
});
```

I've tried using DOMParser on the xml first, but then I just get a string that says [object XMLDocument]. I was trying to do it this way so that I could change the xml based on user input, what worked before was simply putting the XML into the template. Perhaps there is a way to swap component templates dynamically?

**UPDATE SOLVED**

Using *DomSanitizationService*, and *[outerHTML]*, I was able to correctly output my XML string into the DOM.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
import { DomSanitizationService, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
...

  template: `<div [outerHTML]="xml"></div>`

...
})

export class MyClass {

  xml: SafeHtml;

  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService){
    this.xml = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('my valid xml string');
  }

...

}
```

Comment: Please show some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: "toolbox",
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="xml"></div>`
})
class MyComponent {
  xml = 'someXmlString';
}
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868) about how to fix sanitization issues.

Comment: I tried by this and was very confused by the output. With the added DomSanitizerService added in I'm still seeing the output with the xml as a string. In addition the added <div> is an issue as well. I need someway to output just the xml. Here's what I see with this suggested change: <div ngcontent-omm-4 ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="the xml as a string">...</div>

Comment: You can use `[outerHTML]` instead of `[innerHTML]` then the `div` should be replaced by the content.

Comment: Thanks! this appears to have worked, though now I may have a load timing issue. I really appreciate your fast response!

Comment: What you mean with "load timing issues"?

Comment: My external library isn't seeing the xml at the time it's trying to generate the SVG, I'll play around with it a bit though. Thanks again.

Comment: Where do you initialize the external library? You need to wait for `ngAfterViewInit()` to be called.