# SAFE HTML - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, xml, angular

I am printing an XML on my template, and I want to format it.
I have found a file to do this task and it works.

For using it, I have created a `pipe` file:

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import { escape } from 'querystring';

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatXml'
})
export class FormatXmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(xml: string): string {
    var formatted = '';
    var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
    xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');
    var pad = 0;
    jQuery.each(xml.split('\r\n'), function (index, node) {
      var indent = 0;
      if (node.match(/.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/)) {
        indent = 0;
      } else if (node.match(/^<\/\w/)) {
        if (pad != 0) {
          pad -= 1;
        }
      } else if (node.match(/^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/)) {
        indent = 1;
      } else {
        indent = 0;
      }

      var padding = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
        padding += '  ';
      }

      formatted += padding + node + '\r\n';
      pad += indent;
    });

    var escaped = formatted.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '<').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
    //this.trusted(escaped);
    return escaped;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<td *ngIf="i==_rowToShow">{{car.ID| formatXml}}</td>
```

and it also works, but when in print it in the `HTML` it does not change.

I think that my problem is that I do not have a `safe-html`.

I have found a link that explain how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240236/insert-xml-into-dom-in-angular-2) but I am not able to do it. My `HTML` template is already created. How to I send it as parameter to my Pipe?

Comment: you are using a angular2 pipe in an angular 1.x app? Right?

Comment: no. Angular 2 pipe in angular 2 app

Comment: your link is to an angular 1.x app, that's why I am asking

Comment: I know it, but it s the only thing that I have found related to this. I mean, I m formatting correctly the text, but when I show it, it does not work