# Setting to SafeHTML - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `div` which `id` is "carID".

I need to do something like this:

```
magic(){
  //Safe Html is imported previously in the component
  document.getElementById('carID'): SafeHtml
}
```

So basically what I need is to change the type of my div to `SafeHtml`

**Pipe**

I have a Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import { escape } from 'querystring';
import { TestExecutionComponent } from './test-execution/test-execution.component';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//import * as angular from '../angular.js';
//CAMBIAR a string
@Pipe({
  name: 'formatXml'
})
export class FormatXmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  testExecutionComponent: TestExecutionComponent;

  transform(xml: String): SafeHtml {
    var formatted = '';
    var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
    xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');
    var pad = 0;
    jQuery.each(xml.split('\r\n'), function (index, node) {
      var indent = 0;
      if (node.match(/.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/)) {
        indent = 0;
      } else if (node.match(/^<\/\w/)) {
        if (pad != 0) {
          pad -= 1;
        }
      } else if (node.match(/^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/)) {
        indent = 1;
      } else {
        indent = 0;
      }

      var padding = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
        padding += '  ';
      }

      formatted += padding + node + '\r\n';
      pad += indent;
    });

    var escaped = formatted.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '<').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240236/insert-xml-into-dom-in-angular-2
    let safeEscaped = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(escaped);

    return safeEscaped;
    //let safeEscaped = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(escaped);

//return safeEscaped;
  }
}
```

where I use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` with the string.

**Component**

```
  <div id="carDiv" class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordred table-striped ">
                  <tbody *ngIf="cars">
                    <tr *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index;">
                      <td *ngIf="i==_rowToShow" [innerHTML]="car.ID| formatXml"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
```

My code is working. I call from the HTML file to my Pipe, and I get the answer. The problem is that when I print it on the `div`, the string keeps being the same (no format).

I have read that I need to:

- First: Use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` on the string
- Second: Print it on a `SafeHtml`

The post that I am checking is the following: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240236/insert-xml-into-dom-in-angular-2)

I have made the 1st step, so I guess that right now what I need is to use `SafeHtml` for the `Div`.How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Sorry, can't make sense of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**update**

The last 2 lines should be

```
let safeEscaped = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(escaped);

return safeEscaped;
```

**original**

This might do what you want

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

    magic(){
      var safe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(document.getElementById('carID').outerHTML);
    }
}
```

but depending on what the fetched element contains this might be security wise Harakiri with run-up.

Comment: This is what I have previously done, but if I m not wrong, I need to use SafeHtml in the Html (not the string) like here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240236/insert-xml-into-dom-in-angular-2 . So I have already the string, now I need the HTML Div

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't know what you try to accomplish. If you have tried things you should mention that in the question with the result and why and how is didn't what you require.

Comment: Your question still doesn't tell how your posted code doesn't do what you want. My guess is what I posted in my updated answer.

Comment: If I do that, the last return says that I should not return a SafeHtml, just and string. I have changed (just in case it worked) to __export class FormatXmlPipe implements PipeTransform {__
, but it does not work. I have also re-edited the question

Comment: That's becaues `transform(xml: string): string {` is declared to return a `string`. If you change it to `transform(xml: string): SafeHtml {` you should be fine

Comment: I print the same text plus "SafeValue must use [property]=binding" and the beggining

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your last comment, but you probably want `<td *ngIf="i==_rowToShow" [innerHTML]="cars.ID| formatXml"></td>`

Comment: I get nothing. I have re-uploaded the question with with updated code. Now i have the **SafeHtml** in the pipe, and in **InnerHTML**

Comment: If you add `console.log(escaped);` before `let safeEscaped = ...` does it print to the console what you expect to be added to the DOM? Can you create a http://stackblitz.com reproduction?

Comment: Yes I get the value. I ll create it tomorrow morning. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check out this open-source sanitize HTML library for sanitizing the HTML content.

[sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html)

sanitize-HTML provides a simple HTML sanitizer with a clear API.

sanitize-HTML is tolerant. It is well suited for cleaning up HTML fragments such as those created by CKEditor and other rich text editors. It is especially handy for removing unwanted CSS when copying and pasting from Word.

e.g:

```
<div [innerHTML]="senitizeHtmlContent(htmlContent)"></div>

senitizeHtmlContent(value){

  const html = sanitizeHtml(value);

  return html;

}
```