# Correct way Provide DomSanitizer to Component with Angular 2 RC6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm attempting to use DomSanitizer to sanitize a dynamic URL within a Component using I can't seem to figure out what the correct way to specify a Provider for this service is.

I'm using [Angular 2.0.0-rc.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/2.0.0-rc.6)

Here's my current component:

```js
@Component({
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
    providers: [ DomSanitizer ],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
    public url: SafeResourceUrl;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = 'an-id-goes-here';
        let url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`;

         this.videoUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

This results in the error `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl is not a function` at runtime.

Could someone show me an example of how to properly provide a Provider for DomSanitizer? Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

*You don't need to declare **`providers: [ DomSanitizer ]`** anymore*. 
Just need to ***`import`*** ***`DomSanitizer`*** as shown below,

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

in component inject it through a constructor as below,

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

Comment: This was my problem. I was attempting to use `DomSanitizer` as a provider. With no provider at all it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: What if the component that I am trying to use is inside a module that is a sub module. Inside the sub module I am importing CommonModule instead of BrowserModule. How should I provide DomSanitizer to the component inside submodule in that case?

Comment: @TerNovi it has nothing to do with `Module/Submodule`. Just import `DOMSanitizer` as shown in the component itself and use it.

Comment: Ok I did try it. I am not sure if it is because the Submodule is actually part of a library that I have built using ng-packagr. I am consuming this library inside my Application project. However, I still get an error saying no provider has been provided for DomSanitizer. I ended up just doing a native JavaScript implementation to substitute the operation that I was trying to use from DomSanitizer. I am still learning about creating angular packaged libraries so I am not sure if this is affecting the import here. Would you have experience with developing libraries?

Answer (score 14):

Import these-

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

define variable-

```
trustedDashboardUrl : SafeUrl;
```

Use it in constructor like this-

```
constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

Specifiy URL like this-

```
this.trustedDashboardUrl =
                        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl
                            ("URL");
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Do *not* simply circumvent DOM sanitizing! You'll make your page vulnerable to XSS attacks!

Answer (score 7):

It is more easy if you can added custom pipe for **SanitizedHtmlPipe**. because we can use globally in angular project:

- **sanitized-html.pipe.ts**

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
    @Pipe({
      name: 'sanitizedHtml'
    })
    export class SanitizedHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
      transform(value: any): any {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      }
    }
```

- **hero.component.html**

```
    <div [innerHTML]="htmlString | sanitizedHtml"></div>
```

- **hero.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-hero',
      templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
    })
    export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
      htmlString: any;
      constructor() { }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.htmlString = `
        <div class="container">
          <header class="blog-header py-3">
            <div class="row flex-nowrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="col-4 pt-1">
                <a class="text-muted" href="#">Subscribe</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <a class="blog-header-logo text-dark" href="#">Large</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                <a class="text-muted" href="#">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mx-3"><circle cx="10.5" cy="10.5" r="7.5"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15.8" y2="15.8"></line></svg>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Sign up</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>`;
      }
    }
```

For more information you can visit this [link](https://kknebulatech.blogspot.com/2021/07/angular-html-binding.html)

Comment: does anybody even know how to use the sanatize method instead of bypassing securities????

Comment: @nicholaslabrecque This is the danger of StackOverflow. Tons of posts tell people to circumvent warnings instead of properly handling them.

Comment: @LizardKing It's leaking into chatgpt, if you ask it how to use the sanitizer in Angular it suggests "bypassSecurityTrustHtml" LOL

Answer (score 4):

Both should work

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
constructor(private sanitizer: Sanitizer) {}
```

Injecting `DomSanitizer` is better because only this type provides the necessary methods without casting.

Ensure you have imported the `BrowserModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
})
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: it should be `private sanitizer:DomSanitizer` only

Comment: Actually both should work the same https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/979657989bab4fb93faf6a207d30760faa9bd696/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L41

Answer (score 0):

To include this change in ionic, you should add [`IonicSafeString`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/techniques/security)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33046510)