# Set stylesheet href dynamicaly on a component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have build a component and I want to make it more reusable, so I can use it in more projects. I want to pass a stylesheet reference when I create the component on a template, something like this:

```
<dynamic-css [myStyle]= "route/my-stylesheet.css"></dynamic-css>
```

My first aproach is to link it inside the component template, something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [attr.href]="myStyle">
<div>My dynamic-css component content</div>
```

But I don't work, the console throws an error;

> can't find property 'css' of undefined

Here is a dummy version of my component:

```
@Component({
    selector:'dynamic-css',
    template: `
         <link rel="stylesheet" [attr.href]="myStyle">
         <div>My dynamic-css component content</div>
    `
})

export class DynamicCssComponent{
    @Input myStyle:string;
}
```

Is there any aproach to pass a href correctly to the component, or other way to set a stylesheet dynamicaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to surround your bind in quotes '' because the templating engine is looking for the property `css` on a variable by the name of `route/my-stylesheet.css`:

```
<dynamic-css [myStyle]="'route/my-stylesheet.css'"></dynamic-css>
```

Then you'll need to deal with attacks by implementing a pipe to ignore the sanitization per [Correct way Provide DomSanitizer to Component with Angular 2 RC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438039/correct-way-provide-domsanitizer-to-component-with-angular-2-rc6)

> import { Pipe } from "@angular/core"; import { DomSanitizer } from
>   "@angular/platform-browser";
>
> @Pipe({ name: 'safe' }) export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform
>   {   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}   transform(url) {
>       return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);   } }

Finally, declare the pipe in the module and apply the pipe on your component:

**module**

```
import { SafePipe } from "./safe.pipe";
@NgModule({
  <...>
  declarations: [ App, DynamicCssComponent, SafePipe ], <...> }
```

**component** we will bind directly to href with the applied pipe

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]="myStyle | safe">
```

Here's a plunker with a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/UOkl9jqulXklf48iJiuz?p=preview

Comment: I've worrked arround with the DomSanitize previously, but seems that my real problem was that single quotes in the property binding:  [myStyle]="'route/my-stylesheet.css'". Thanks!