# Jasmine doesn't recognize Angular's DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, jasmine, testbed, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am unit testing an Angular 5 app with Jasmine. I got to the point where I need to test a function that relies on the `DomSanitizer`:

```
loadImage() {
  this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${this.assetUrl})`);
}
```

I verified that this function works perfectly, meaning that `DomSanitizer` is already in the constructor and it's syntax is correct.

My unit test is as follows:

```
it('loads the Image', () => {
    component.loadImage()
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.imageUrl).toBe('...');
  });
```

Moreover, `DomSanitizer` is part of the `TestBed` `providers`:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        DomSanitizer
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Yet, Jasmine throws this error when unit-testing the function:

```
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', '_this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle is not a function', '; Zone:', 'angular', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', TypeError: _this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `DomSanitizer` from the providers, and instead of the `CommonModule`, try to use the `BrowserModule`

Comment: You need to Import `BrowserModule` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438039/correct-way-provide-domsanitizer-to-component-with-angular-2-rc6

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

change it to be BrowserModule instead of CommonModule and also, DomSanitizer can be ommited:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        BrowserModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ]
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```