# I get unsafe URL when trying to view video using its path

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using IONIC and retrieving the URL from the server, I can see the URL when using `<p>` tags as follows:

```
<p>{{URL}}</p>
```

but when I try the following:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{URL}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I get an error (`Get` request error) that says "Unsafe url"

I find people suggesting to use `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` like in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438039/correct-way-provide-domsanitizer-to-component-with-angular-2-rc6) but unfortunately, it didn't work for me

NOTE: the video is located inside the project folders, and the URL is retrieved from the database.

How can I enable the `<video>` tag to play videos from the project directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be permission issue, try to change the project directory to a different drive, for example, if it is located in "C" drive, move it elsewhere.