# Angular 2 treating gradients as unsafe

Tags: css, angular, xss, gradient

I'm trying to set a gradient on a component dynamically and am getting the following warning:

`WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value linear-gradient(#000,#00f) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`

Here's a minimal reproduction:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1 [style.background]="(\'linear-gradient(#000,#00f)\')">My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

My googling tells me to use `bypassSecurityTrustStyle` but I'm not happy doing that until I know

1. Why is linear gradient considered unsafe?
2. Is this intended behaviour or just a bug with the current version of Angular 2.
3. Is there a better way to do this without it being considered unsafe?

This does have to be dynamic as I'm building the gradient string programatically. I can't use css classes for this.

Comment: Are you using the DomSanitationService? See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8491#issuecomment-217467582 and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: Yeah the `DomSanitationService` is where all the `bypassSecurityTrust*` stuff lives.  I'm not convinced that it should be needed for gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed in Angular 2.4.4 (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#244-2017-01-19)

PR: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13943/files

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Why is linear gradient considered unsafe?

There are restrictions under which misses your style (specifically brackets)

```
linear-gradient(#000,#00f)
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.7/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/security/style_sanitizer.ts#L30

As of today (RC.7) the RegExp looks like

```
/^([-,."'%_!# a-zA-Z0-9]+|(?:(?:matrix|translate|scale|rotate|skew|perspective)(?:X|Y|3d)?|(?:rgb|hsl)a?)\([-0-9.%, a-zA-Z]+\))$/g
```

[image]

> 2) Is this intended behaviour or just a bug with the current version
>   of Angular 2.

I think it is more the expected behavior than the bug

Related issue on github

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11158

> 3) Is there a better way to do this without it being considered
>   unsafe?

You can work around this limitation via writing **CustomDomSanitizer**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ { provide: DomSanitizer, useClass: CustomDomSanitizer } ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See also live **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/I7TBvt3REaGjqLTAC5yd?p=preview)**

Comment: That "workaround" just disables sanitisation globally... That seems like a terrible idea.  I still don't understand why linear-gradient isn't in that regex whitelist. Is it actually unsafe or is it an oversight?

Comment: FWIW, I've sent https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13943 to support this use case. Consider filing an issue in the future, this is really just an oversight in the CSS validator!