# How to display code within <code>-tag in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to show code snippets within my angular2 application. But I am not able to paste simple javascript code within a code-tag.

I always need to add a second curly bracket and I have to add ngNonBindable. But I don't want to add a second bracket.

Has anyone a solution to this?

http://plnkr.co/edit/OzlHLJxgwSvUffryV3e4

this is my app.component.html:

```
<h1>Here is the documentation for the model:</h1>
<pre>
  <code ngNonBindable>
    export model = new Model({
      a:1,
      b:function(){}
    })
  </code>
</pre>
```

The User should see:

```
here is the documentation for the model:

export model = new Model({
     a:1,
     b:function(){}
 })`
```

Comment: did you try `<code ngNonBindable [innerHtml]='model'></code>` ?

Comment: yes, but i'd like to have it within the template, to have more comfort, instead of having a lot of variables with the code-content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use `[innerHTML]="xxx"` and hold the code in the components class

```
<pre>
  <code [innerHTML]="code"></code>
</pre>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  code = `
export model = new Model({
  a:1,
  b:function(){}
})
`
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0Ii7l3Fy3cPzXYAiUde?p=preview)

[In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868) might also be helpful.

Comment: Well, yes, that is a possible way, but I plan to have a lot of code-snippets within the template. It would be more comfortable to have it directly within the template file.

Comment: I guess then you need to escape every `{` and every `}` as `{{'{'}}` and `{{'}'}}`. There is an open issue as far as I remember to make `ngNonBindable` work here.

Comment: thanx, I will use your solution above.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and ended up replacing all curly braces with a numerical character reference. e.g:

```
<pre>
  <code>
    export model = new Model(&#123;
      a:1,
      b:function()&#123;&#125;
    &#125;)
  </code>
</pre>
```

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ubAME2iNKF62oxrKmmjb?p=preview)