# Typescript/Angular 2 doesn't display html into a ternary

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The following will display it as text (with<\i class.. backslash and without ) and not as HTML, probably very simple, but I can't find it :(

```
<div *ngFor="let facility of facilities;">
    {{facility['freewifi'] || facility['paidwifi'] ? '<\i class="fa fa-wifi fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"><\/i> :' : '' }}
</div>
```

Answer:

```
<i *ngIf="facility['freewifi'] || facility['paidwifi']" class="fa fa-wifi fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` property?

Comment: use `*ngIf`: `<i *ngIf="facility['freewifi'] || facility['paidwifi']" class="..."></i>`

Comment: Might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: @HarryNinh , that's it! Can you put this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*ngIf` instead:

```
<i *ngIf="facility['freewifi'] || facility['paidwifi']" class="fa fa-wifi fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```