# How to dynamically add innerHTML with angular 2 components

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I'm creating docs for a component library. I want 1 string of html that generates both the component on the page and the docs for it.

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

When I inspect the HTML, my-button tags are not present. They are being stripped out when I use innerHTML.

My component code:

```
private flatButtons = `<div class="button-wrapper">
      <my-button [type]="'default'" [raised]="false">Default</my-button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <my-button [type]="'primary'" [raised]="false">Primary</my-button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <my-button [type]="'success'" [raised]="false">Success</my-button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <my-button [type]="'info'" [raised]="false">Info</my-button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <my-button [type]="'warning'" [raised]="false">Warning</my-button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <my-button [type]="'danger'" [raised]="false">Danger</my-button>
    </div>`

constructor() {}

getCode() {
    return html_beautify(this.flatButtons, this.options)
}
```

My HTML template:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <mi-card title="Flat Buttons" baCardClass="with-scroll button-panel">
    <div id="flatButtons" [innerHTML]="getCode()">
    </div>
  </mi-card>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <pre>{{getCode()}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect the picture after "What I want:"

Comment: Ok, so you expect the added HTML to become actual Angular components. That doesn't work this way. See my answer.

Comment: this worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43862386/1048800

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/apoterenko/angular2-dynamic-component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular doesn't process HTML added dynamically, it just adds it verbatim except some sanitization to prevent security issues. 
See [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868) for how to prevent the sanitizer of stripping the HTML.

You can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` like shown in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) to add components dynamically.

There are also solutions available how to create components dynamically like shown in [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960)

Answer (score 0):

I'll accept Gunter's answer since it answers my question.

For those who are interested, the way I solved my problem was by creating a component and requiring it.

I created a dumb component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'flat-buttons',
  template: require('./flatButtons.html'),
})
export class FlatButtons {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

And then my modified html template:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <mi-card title="Flat Buttons" baCardClass="with-scroll button-panel">
    <flat-buttons></flat-buttons>
  </mi-card>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <h3>Code Snippet</h3>
  <div class="well">
    <pre>{{getFlatButtons()}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my modified component code:

```
private flatButtons = require('./components/flatButtons/flatButtons.html')

constructor() {}

getFlatButtons() {
    return html_beautify(this.flatButtons, this.options)
}
```

Comment: collinglass, how does your flatButtons.html look like? Can you share?