# Angular2 [innerHtml] angular2 tag doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml

I want to inject html in my a-component with angular2 tags from another component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<app-a [my-html]="my-html"> </app-a>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  my-html= '<span> {{variableFromAComponent}}</span>';
}



@Component({
      selector: 'app-a',
      template: '<div [innerHtml]="my-html"> </div>',
    })
    export class AComponent {
      @Input('my-html') my-html:any;
      public variableFromAComponent='its work!'; 
    }
```

I want to see in result : its work! (from  variableFromAComponent)  But i see {{variableFromAComponent}} (angular2 tags doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution in [angular2-dynamic-component](https://github.com/apoterenko/angular2-dynamic-component)

```
<template dynamic-component
          [componentContext]="self"
          [componentModules]="dynamicExtraModules"
          [componentTemplate]='"here html tags with angular2 tags"'>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't process HTML added by `[innerHTML]="..."` at all. It is just added as is and that's it. You might even need to use the Sanitizer, so nothing gets stripped for security reasons (see [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)).

If you want to dynamically add components, you can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` for example like explained in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: Of course not. As I said, Angular2 doesn't create components for HTML added this way.

Comment: i watched your example for loading dynamic tabs. I don't want to load components, i want load my html with Angular2 tags. My task - load html with angular2 tags from server and rendered it in another components.

Comment: There are answers that show how to create new components at runtime. That's the only way to create components from HTML loaded at runtime. Search for `$compile` (only on the phone right now)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I took  [angular2-dynamic-component](https://github.com/apoterenko/angular2-dynamic-component)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways that you can do this.

[COMPONENT INTERACTION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

If there is a parent/child relationship between the components then you can use `Input()` and `Output()` to pass values between them

This child component gets the value through the `Input()`

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<div>{{myHtml}}</div>', // these curly braces add the text as innerHTML
  providers: [ FoodsService]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() myHtml: string;
}
```

which is passed from the parent through the template:

**parent.component.html**

```
<child [myHtml]="'You're String Here (or a variable set to "its work")'"></child>
```

You can use `Output()` to go from child to parent.

[SERVICES](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

The other way is to create a service that gets injected into both components. One component can send a value to the service and the other can get that value. In Angular2 this is often achieved by using [observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) to a data object.

Comment: I did not just use innerHtml. I tried you solution, as a result - html tags and angular2 tags doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Renderer2 Class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html) for this.

```
import { ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

constructor (
  private elementRef: ElementRef,
  private renderer: Renderer
) {}

public ngAfertViewInit(): void {
  this.renderer
     .setElementProperty(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, 
        'innerHTML',
        '<h1> Nice Title </h1>'
     );
}
```

Comment: @Andrei I was able to render d3 graphs with this on the server last week, it is experimental but if doesn't work for you use the Renderer class instead.