# Twine-like game in Angular 4 - dynamically loading html templates

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to implement a game much like those created with the tool [Twine](https://twinery.org). An  example can be found [here](http://ifarchive.jmac.org/if-archive/games/competition2016/16%20Ways%20to%20Kill%20a%20Vampire%20at%20McDonalds/Vampire%20(43).html) (no need to go past the first few pages to understand what I'm going for). Basically, it's a choose your own adventure game where a player moves between chunks of html (called passages) containing static text and interactive elements, like buttons that show more text and links to other passages.

I dislike using Twine 2 (it's frustrating and limited for experienced programmers) and thought it would be better to implement my game using a modern web framework, like Angular. However, Angular doesn't appear to allow you to dynamically load html containing Angular components -- see [How to dynamically add innerHTML with angular 2 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473910/how-to-dynamically-add-innerhtml-with-angular-2-components) -- you have to explicitly load the components themselves.

If I wanted dynamically loaded passages to contain angular components, would I have to write a separate component for each passage? Are there any performance/maintenance issues with this?