# Angular 2 innerhtml from webservice, parse variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm pretty new to Angular 2 - and have a "simple" question

I have a web service, which delivers content to a view .. in a web service response i want to loop a member array in the template ..

eg.

name = 'testtest';

feed = [{title: 'test'}, {title: 'test42'}];

**view.html:**

```
<div class="content" [innerHTML]="page._content"></div>
```

**view.ts:**

```
this.page['_content'] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.page['content']);
```

**web service html: this.page['content']:**

```
{{name}} <li class="item" *ngFor="let entry of feed"> ....
```

**result:**

```
{{name}}
```

Comment: You can't bind angular templating syntax into [innerHTML]. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40473910/6678754) for a possible approach.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if this solves your problem, of binding angular syntaxes into `[innerHTML]`

[The Fantabulous ng-dynamic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic)

and it's usage is also pretty simple:

```
<div *dynamicComponent="your_html_string">loadin</div>
```

It binds with angular2+ directives

Good Luck